# Why do I get the error "Server Creation Failed: "Class not Registered"?

Tags: matlab, com

I am creating a COM server (using `actxserver`) for CSTStudio using MATLAB, but I'm getting the error

> Class not regiestred in feval

which is working inside actxserver. Also when I tried to create COM server for other applications such as Word and PowerPoint it is working fine but showing an error for the `invoke` function.

Here is the MATLAB Code:

```
addpath(genpath('G:\MATLAB\CST-MATLAB-API-master'));

cst = actxserver('CSTStudio.application');

mws = cst.invoke('NewMWS');
```

This is the error:

> MicrostripAntenna
>
> Error using feval
>
> Server Creation Failed: Class not registered
> Error in actxserver (line 89)
> h=feval(['COM.' convertedProgID], 'server', machinename, interface);
> Error in MicrostripAntenna (line 32)
> cst = actxserver('CSTStudio.application');

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean by saying it is "working for other applications." Do you mean you can create those objects or that from within those programs you can create `CSTStudio.application`? #1 is CSTStudio installed on that computer? Is there a registry entry for the ProgId on the computer? Is it an in-process (.dll) or local server (.exe)?

My first suggestion is that you use VB Script to try and diagnose whether it is a 32/64-bit mismatch and whether the server is even on the machine.

Take this VB Script and save it to a file called CSTStudioTest.vbs

```
dim app
set app = CreateObject("CSTStudio.application")
MsgBox TypeName(app)
```

Change directory to where the newly created file exists.

Then, execute the script in two different ways:

```
c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe CSTStudioTest.vbs
```

and also as

```
c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe CSTStudioTest.vbs
```

If both succeed, then that means CSTStudio is a local server (.exe)

If one succeeds, then that means CSTStudio is an in-process server (.dll) and that it means it will only work with programs of the same bitness. If only the first script succeeded, it means CSTStudio server is a 64-bit in process server. If only the second script succeeds, it means it is a 32-bit in process server. If it is an in process server, then you can only directly call it from a process that has the same bitness (64 bit from 64 bit, or 32 bit from 32 bit).

If both of those scripts fail, that means CSTStudio is not installed correctly on your computer (if at all).

If the bitness between MATLAB and CSTStudio is different, the easiest remedy is to get a version of MATLAB or CSTStudio that matches the bitness of the other.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Both commands works well with "CSTStudio.application.2016". So, My code starts working after adding .2016 (The CSTStudio version installed in my PC) to my actxserver function i.e cst = actxserver('CSTStudio.application.2016');.. Thank you once again.